# Differentiate windows copy & cut action in Qt GUI Application

Tags: qt, clipboard

How to identify if data in QClipboard is result of cut or copy of windows action ?
For e.g select the folder in windows explorer, press Ctrl+X (cut action), now activate Qt GUI application and paste it. now Qt application needs some mean to identify previous windows action if it needs to delete selected folder(in case of cut action in windows explorer) or not(in case of copy action in windows explorer)

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I have the same issue, I need to cut between applications and am not sure how to tell my application this. (clearly there must be SOME way!)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this.  The clipboard simply holds data.  In fact, I don't think any operating system distinguishes between copy and cut.  Cutting is essentially copying and then deleting the data at the source.

*edit:
The only way I could think to do this would be to have your application monitor key presses.  So if the user ever types Ctrl+X you know they've cut.  However that won't help if they right click to cut.  Either way, it's not a great solution.

Comment: May be windows API could have some way to identify cut-copy even from right click, as on cut folder/file symbol gets blurred(disable state) in explorer. may be some windows API to check symbol state(enable/disable) of clipboard path

Comment: I am not able to find any windows API to get such icon state. it seems, explorer is blending the icons on cut to look like disabled state.